# Getting file path from project directory using C in iOS

Tags: ios, c, swift

I am doing an `iOS` project right now. Currently, I have this situation that I need to open a certain file that resides in my project directory. This is a swift project that bridges source from c.

> Project -> Folder -> File

The trick is, I want to access it in my .c file, I've already tried to do it like this "/Folder/file.ext" and by using Bundle.main.path but the file would be NULL.

`file = fopen(filepath, "rb");`

I checked other questions but most has been for ObjC. Is this implementation possible or do I need to somehow my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error that `fopen` gives you? You can check with `strerror(errno)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to pass in the directory from your Objective-C app (or Swift, if that's what you're using). You can get it by doing the usual way of getting a file's path in your bundle, but calling `UTF8String` on the `NSString` object you get, like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file" withExtension:@"ext"].absoluteString.UTF8String
```

However, be sure to copy the string that returns, as it's a pointer that will not live in memory longer than the `NSString` it comes from, which should be deallocated almost immediately after you use it